# angular 6 custom material icons with ligature support

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, google-material-icons, ligature

Is it possible to create custom material icons with ligature support.
I am currently using `svgIcon` for getting Custom Icons,
Is there any way to achieve ligature supported custom icons?

My current code snippet is given as below

> **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
  })
  export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';

    constructor(
      iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
      sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) {
      iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('key',
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/icons/key.svg')
      );
      iconRegistry.addSvgIcon('user',
        sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('assets/icons/user.svg')
      );
    }

  }
```

> **login.component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username">
  <mat-icon matPrefix svgIcon="user"></mat-icon>
  <mat-error *ngIf="username.invalid">Username is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password">
  <mat-icon matPrefix svgIcon="key"></mat-icon>
  <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid">Password is required</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure its possible:

**Step 1)** Get all the SVG icons.

**Step 2)** Create your font with a custom ligature.

> This is a tool, to create your own font library with ligature support.
>   https://icomoon.io

**Step 3:**

Declare your own font.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src: url('path.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

**Step 4:**
Override the `.material-icons` with you own font

```
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'MyFontFamily';
   ...
}
```

or declare your own `fontSet` so you can work with both.

```
// Register to AppComponent

 constructor(iconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
    iconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias('MyFontFamily', 'MyIconClass');
 }
```

**Last step.**

```
<mat-icon>LigatureToDisplay</mat-icon>
```

**OR**

```
<mat-icon fontSet="MyIconClass">LigatureOrUnicodeToDisplay</mat-icon>
```

> Here is a small tutorial.
>
> https://medium.com/@buddhiv/add-a-custom-icon-font-in-your-application-b1e07a687953